# calling jsp file from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

i have three servlet. In first servlet i have Request Dispatcher so it is redirect to my Dynamic List.jsp file. The jsp file contains

```
<div  class='feedItem'> <c:out value="${feed.tagRuleType}"> </c:out> </div>
<div  class='feedItem'><input type="submit" value="Update"   onClick="updateRows(${feed.configId})"></div>
<div  class='feedItem'><input type="submit" value="Delete"   onClick="deleteRows(${feed.feedId})"></div>
```

When i click on the update button i can able to call the servlet through javascript. Inside servlet i am using Request Dispatcher:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/FeedUpdate.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

But it is not redirecting to FeedUpdate.jsp file

It is iterating the list object. Inside the tag i added update button. so when i click update button corresponding row id i will get for updating a record.

When i click the button i can able to call servlet and the get the id. when i redirect to the jsp page using Request Dispatcher inside the servlet it is not redirecting to jsp page.

Can anyone the give the suggestion why it is not redirecting to jsp file.

Comment: Did your server encountered any errors?

Comment: Depends on how you're confirming that the *forward* is not happening. A redirect is not the same thing as a forward. Are you going by what you're seeing in the address bar of browser?

Answer (score 1):

if you have used Jquery Ajax call to call your servlet, your dispatcher forward won't work. You may want do the redirect in the success method of Ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url : "servlet",
  data : param,
  success : function(data) {
     windows.location.href='/myservlet?id='+data;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to call other method in another JSP and takes id as the parameter, if yes, then you can do it this way :

```
<h3>Sections List</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty listSections}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="80">Section ID</th>
            <th width="120">Section name</th>
            <th width="120">Section size</th>
            <th width="120">Section position</th>
            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listSections}" var="section">
            <tr>
                <td>${section.sectionid}</td>
                <td>${section.sectionname}</td>
                <td>${section.sectionsize}</td>
                <td>${section.sectionposition}</td>

                <td><a href="<c:url value='/editsection/${section.sectionid}' />" >Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/removesection/${section.sectionid}' />" >Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

The method editSetion and RemoveSection can be in different JSP files as well, depends how you have mapped it. Is this what you are looking for? I cannot understand exactly what you want, as you have not provided much information, no code too.. Please add more code and properly explain if this is not what you expected.

Comment: Ok, I am updating my post to make sure I understand you.

Comment: Hello, No, You are not posting relevant information, how are you handling the update function? the name of JSp is casesensitive, where are details of update function.. Is name of JSP correct, it is case sensitive, plus why are you using '/' infront of JSP filename?